# What if 2 header file contain same function

Tags: c, header-files

What if 2 header file contain same function  with same declaration, and I have included both the header file in my c program and I have called the common method then what will happen?

Comment: Did you try it out?

Comment: check it out :)

Comment: Do you mean declare the same function, or contain the same function body?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: the compiler will generate redefinition error.
When you request to use a header file, you tell the preprocessor to add the code of the header file at the place of the declaration (#include ""). Therefore when including two header files that each contains the same function declaration, the compiler will see two identical declarations and produce an error.
tutorial about header files: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm

Answer (score 0):

If the declarations are the same, nothing will happen. The program will compile and work as expected.

If the definition of the function is included in the header a compiler redefinition error will occur.

If the declarations are the same but the implementations are different and are in different files a linker error will occur.